# Access childs in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Database View]

I am using firebase realtime database but i cannot access the date,description and other fields when i use this code below:

```
let dataRef = firebase.database().ref().child('cars');
dataRef.on('value', function(data) {
console.log(data.val());
});
```

It returns all the childs in the **cars** node as a single object

Output: **Object { "-LGixH1Hbjb01pVGa9AM": {…}, "-LGixXbCcbv082aohG3E": {…}, "-LGixnOd80UjF6PlSNhL": {…} }**

Is there a way to access name value pairs inside the Keys(that are -LGixH1Hbjb01pVGa9AM,-LGixXbCcbv082aohG3E,-LGixnOd80UjF6PlSNhL)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let dataRef = firebase.database().ref().child('cars');
 dataRef.on('value', function(data) {
 data.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    let date=childSnapshot.val().date;
    let description=childSnapshot.val().description;
  });
});
```

The snapshot is at `cars`, you then loop inside the ids using `forEach` and retrieve the data that you want.